# Load different images based on screen width

Tags: polymer

I am developing a bootstrap carousel using polymer in my website. There are two types of images I wanted to display depending upon the screen width. I have written a code for the same, but the problem here is that the images are not changing when the width is changed. Thank you in advance!

```
<dom-module id="carousel">

<style>

    :host {
        display: block;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>


<template>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom:0px; z-index:1;">
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner center" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src= "{{ img1 }}" >
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src= "{{ img2 }}" >
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>             

</template>


<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'carousel',

        properties: {
            img1: { type: String, notify: true },
            img2: { type: String, notify: true },
        },

        ready: function() {
            this.methodToFixLayout();
            $(window).on( "resize", this.methodToFixLayout );
        },

        methodToFixLayout: function() {
            var windowsize = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            if( windowsize > 1000 ) {
                this.img1 = "//large01.jpg";
                this.img2 = "//large02.jpg";
            } else {
                this.img1 = "//small01.jpg";
                this.img2 = "//small02.jpg";
            }
        },

    });

</script>
```

Comment: There are two options that I know of that could make things easier for you. There is the HTML5 `picture` element that will use different image sources depending on the screen width. You can read about it [here](http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/) although be warned that it only works on [very new browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture). You could also use the [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) element to show different images depending on the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use iron-image which is an element for displaying an image that provides useful sizing and preloading options not found on the standard  tag as stated in the doc [iron-image](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-image). Because you will make you application more heavier with multiples images to match to specific screens.(Responsive is always better).
Anyway If you want to use your element as it is , you better take advantage of 
[iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) to data bind to multiple media query. Here is a more elaborated implementation of your carousel element, Hope it helps

```
<dom-module id="my-carousel">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }

    img {
      width: 100 %;
      height: 100 %;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 1;">
          <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner center" role="listbox">

          <!-- use is dom-repeat -->
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{images}}" as="item">
            <div class="item">
              <img src$="{{_selectImage(item)}}" class$="{{ _isActive(item.active)}}"/>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iron-media-query -->
    <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 601px)" query-matches="{{_isMobile}}"></iron-media-query>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      //Caution: an element name must ALWAYS contain a dash
      is: 'my-carousel',
      properties: {
        //Using Array for your images 
        images: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [{
              small: '//small01.jpg',
              large: '//large01.jpg',
              active: true
            }, {
             small: '//small02.jpg',
             large: '//large02.jpg',
            active: false
            }];
          }
        },
        //true when min-width=601px
        _isMobile: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false,
          notify: true
        }
      },

      // return the status of the image
      _isActive: function(item) {
        return item.active === true ? 'active' : '';
      },

      _selectImage: function(item) {
        if (_isMobile) {
          return item.small;
        } else {
          return item.large;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't load the images even in the Network.

Comment: I edited the answer, make sure to use the right path to the image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution turned out to be pretty simple. Just made the following changes in Polymer.

```
Polymer({

    is: 'carousel',

    behaviors: [
                Polymer.IronResizableBehavior
            ],

    listeners: {
        'iron-resize': '_onIronResize'
    },

    properties: {
        img1: { type: Image, notify: true },
        img2: { type: Image, notify: true },
    },

    _onIronResize: function() {
        var windowsize = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        if( windowsize > 600 ) {
            this.img1 = "//large-1.jpg";
            this.img2 = "//large-2.jpg";
        } else {
            this.img1 = "//small-1.jpg";
            this.img2 = "//small-2.jpg";
        }
    },

    });
```